Archivo no existe smarty/templatefinder
Tengo una instalación de prestashop en la cual el buscador, sin motivo aparente, ha dejado de funcionar. He puesto la pagina en modo debug y me salta continuamente el mismo error:
No template found for /usr/home/einatall.com/web/themes/classic/search.tpl
at line 68 in file classes/Smarty/TemplateFinder.php
63.                     return $tpl;
64.                 }
65.             }
66.         }
67. 
68.         throw new PrestaShopException('No template found for '.$template);
69.     }
70. 
71.     private function getTemplateHierarchy($template, $entity, $id)
72.     {
73.         $entity = basename($entity);

Según esto estoy entendiendo no está encontrando el archivo search.tpl en la ruta que me indica. Ese archivo si que existe en la ruta y tiene permisos 644. Dejo el codigo por si hay algo mal que no logro ver del search.tpl:
{*
 * Template customization for search page with additional Step 1
 *}
{extends file='catalog/listing/product-list.tpl'}

{block name='page_content'}
    <div class="search-step">
        <h1>Step 1: Search Form</h1>
        <form action="{url entity='search'}" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="search-results">
        {include file='catalog/_partials/product-list.tpl'}
    </div>
{/block}

He leido que tengo que borrar el SearchController.php pero si lo hago deja de funcionar, por lo tanto no lo puedo borrar. También he desinstalado el modulo (viene por defecto) y lo he vuelto a instalar y sigue dando el mismo problema.
